# Tortoise SVN "Can't read from connection error"

Tags: windows, svn, networking, tortoisesvn

I have installed SVN server and try to access it using Tortoise SVN client. During the checkout/update process I randomly get an error "Can't read from connection. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". Some files are loaded (but sometimes not from the first time).

I have googled a lot of similar problems, but haven't found any solution.

UPD. I have tested it from other PC - no problems. So probably the problem is with my network configuration. I'm trying to access SVN installed on my desktop using notebook connected using Wi-Fi.

Comment: What platform / server / OS are client and server on? Are you behind a firewall? What does your network setup look like?

Comment: Also, what port are you using? Is it running over SSL?

Comment: As some files are downloaded, I think it is not OS/firewall problem. For sure firewall is disabled and my OS is Windows 7.

No SSS.

Comment: Probably the problem is with my Wi-Fi adapter that I in ad-hoc mode. There are no problems checkouting using Ethernet. Will try to remove Wi-Fi adapter by roater.

Answer (score -2):

So as you discovered the answer is to check your network connection for a problem.